# How to Loop table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code which works fine for one table but I am trying to figure out how to make it loop.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(1000) 

SELECT @table = ( VV.SRC_CD ) 
FROM   VV 

SET @sql = 'SELECT [CD],[SRC_CD],[SRC_CD_DESC],[DSC],[REFRESH_DT],[GEN_DSC] = CAST(null as VARCHAR(50))      INTO dbo.vv_' + @table 
           + 
' FROM [vv] A WHERE A.SRC_CD <> ''GEN''      AND A.DSC <> ''NO DATA'' AND A.DSC <> ''(BLANK) NO'' AND A.src_cd = ''' 
           + @table + '''' 

EXEC Sp_executesql 
  @stmt = @sql
```

The code that populates the @table variable returns one row.  What I am trying to do is get this procedure to loop one time for each distinct value in the table for that row.  The distinct clause doesn't work here and I have tried a basic table array with no luck.

Do I need to modify this to use a cursor?

Comment: What are the possible values for @table variable? Not real sure of your question without seeing some example data.

Comment: If I run the following query:

    select distinct(vv.SRC_CD) from vv

A few possible values are:
AC
ACI
AG
AID
AL
AP
AR
AS
AT
AVS
BA
BD

Comment: And you want to run that @sql text for each of those return values? If so, you CAN do a CURSOR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're in need of a cursor, something like:

```
DECLARE @Iterator NVARCHAR(100)
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
--Select stuff to iterate over
SELECT DISTINCT SRC_CD
FROM w

OPEN xyz 
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--Do stuff
SET @sql = 'SELECT [CD],[SRC_CD],[SRC_CD_DESC],[DSC],[REFRESH_DT],[GEN_DSC] = CAST(null as VARCHAR(50)) 
            INTO dbo.vv_' + @Iterator +' 
            FROM [vv] A 
            WHERE A.SRC_CD <> ''GEN'' 
                 AND A.DSC <> ''NO DATA'' 
                 AND A.DSC <> ''(BLANK) NO'' 
                 AND A.src_cd = ''' + @Iterator + ''''
PRINT (@sql)    

    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator 
END

CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

I left `PRINT` in there so you can ensure the output is as desired before executing.